# Storing user defined options

Tags: php, mysql

I'm going to start work on a new project in which I'll give the owner of the site the ability to fine tune various options to their liking - E.G website name, a few theme colours and things of that nature.

I'm just curious as to what the best method of storing these options is - do I use a database table and return the values with queries or would it be best to set these options in a single `configuration.php` file for example?

Comment: Some use database, some use a config.php, it's really up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a config file, there is rarely a good reason to do a database lookup for owner-defined constants every page load.  The only benefit to keeping them in a database is if you plan on making a content management system where the owner can change the config values through a UI, and then he/she won't be coming to you to make those changes in the code. Even then I'd keep those cached somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I would say to go ahead and use a database, just make sure all of the data is sanitized.

Comment: Using a database, although common, is pretty bad for options as it wreaks havoc with things like source control. Checking in the database structure and the code/config files should be acceptable instead of having to check in the entire contents of the database as well.